# Combining optional chaining and ifs

Tags: swift

I found out, that I can write this code:

```
func optionalReturn() -> Int? {
    // do sth. and return maybe an Int, otherwise:
    return nil
}

if let x = optionalReturn(), x > 5 {
    print("test exists and is greater then 5")
}
```

Now I'm standing in front of the following problem: I want to have an if, that handles two cases:

- case 1: `x` is not existing, OR
- case 2: `x` is existing, but is greater than value 5

This is not working:

```
if x == nil || (let x = optionalReturn(), x > 5) {
    ...
}
```

Is sth. like this possible in Swift?

**UPDATE**

The above code was simplified to show my problem, but my case is a little bit different, because my called function doesn't return an optional `Int`, it returns an optional `struct`:

```
struct TestStruct {
    var x: Int
    var y: Int
}

func optionalReturn() -> TestStruct? {
    // do sth. and maybe return a TestStruct(....), otherwise:
    return nil
}

let test = optionalReturn()

if test == nil || ...?
```

**UPDATE 2**

In my first update I had a mistake. Thanks to Christik, who mentioned it in the comments, my code had a mistake and would have worked without it. I accepted his answer as a solution, but my first idea was right as well: Swift skips the other if-conditions, if the first OR-condition is true. So this code works as well:

```
...

if test == nil || (test!.x > 5 && test!.y > 6) {
    print("I am here")
}
```

Comment: You mistyped first condition in the `if`, it should be `test == nil`, not `test != nil`

Comment: you meant x (in the first example it's x). I corrected it, thx!

Comment: Nope, I meant in the second example, the first example was correct. That's why your code was crashing, because the forced unwrap was happening only when `test` was nil

Comment: Aaah, how stupid am I? I updated my post, because my first idea was right (that's cool :)). Thank you so much for your help, I think there are now two nice solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nil coalescing operator here, and give `x` a value greater than 5, if its nil:

```swift
if (x ?? 6) > 5 {
    // do your thing
}
```

In regards to the question update, you can use `map` on the optional to achieve your goal:

```swift
if x.map({ $0.x > 5 && $0.y > 6 }) ?? true {
    // do your thing
}
```

`map` has the advantage that it avoids the forced unwrap.

Comment: Thanks! That’s a great way, if x is just an `Int`. In my real case, I have a `struct`-instance and I am comparing several properties, so: `if x != nil || (x.a > 5 && x.b > 6)`.

Comment: @Lupurus Please update your question with your real case or create an example that reflect your real case.

Comment: @Lupurus then please state this into the question, don't keep us in the dark trying to give you half-answers to a half-question.

Comment: @Lupurus updated the answer to also cover the edit of the question.

Comment: That's fantastic, it works!!! I love Swift so much! :) Thought, that .map is only possible for collection types. Didn't knew, that you can call it on Optionals. May I bet you to explain, what map is doing exactly? The `map<U>(_ transform: ...` evaluates the given closure when the value is not nil: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/optional/1539476-map